# how to make title in TOCropViewController CocoaPod?

Tags: swift3, cocoapods

I need to add a title bar named "Crop Image" in this Cocoapod.
[image]
Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the developer of `TOCropViewController`. :)

There's no feature in the library at the moment to display text above the cropping content right now. But it would be fairly trivial to add a `UILabel` to the view and position it near the top of the view.

The challenge is that you'd then need to account for it when the device is rotated sideways. At the moment, the cropping content will fill the entire height of a horizontal device, so you'd need to override that to account for the text.

It's been a while since I wrote it, but I did include a property in the vertical layout code to add padding to the top of the view controller, so it SHOULD be relatively easy.

I sadly don't have time to add it myself, but I made [an issue on the repo](https://github.com/TimOliver/TOCropViewController/issues/163) and added the `pr requested` tag. Hopefully someone with more free time than I do can add it. :)

Comment: Just to provide proper closure, setting a title has now been added as an official API. :D